# Update a file with convert to Google driver with pydrive Gives: ApiRequestError: HttpError 500 Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am trying to update an existing file in `Google drive` using `python script`.

The code that I am using is:

```
fileID = wasFileUploadedBefore(drive, reportName) #this gets the fileID if it's already in GDrive
if fileID != 0:
   reportFile = drive.CreateFile({'id': fileID})
else:
   reportFile = drive.CreateFile({'title':reportName, 'mimeType':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
reportFile.SetContentFile(reportName)
reportFile.Upload({'convert':True}) #convert=true is to convert the file to GoogleDrive Spreadsheet.
```

As I said when I am running the code the following error occurs:

```
raise ApiRequestError(error)
ApiRequestError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/....&convert=true&alt=json returned "Internal Error">
```

Everything is good if I don't use {`'convert':True}` tag in Upload, but I really need it because I want the file to be converted.

I'm trying to upload an `.xlsx` file

Comment: try:  ({'convert':true})

Comment: It`s not working. I`ve tried also with ({'convert':'true'})

Comment: any reason you are not using Googles example and client lib?

Comment: I will try google-api if I won`t find a solution. I was really curious why this is not working

Comment: probably something in the code you are using Google doesn't have upload its insert. So there is no way of knowing if convert is even supported in that code. you have there.

Comment: Try uploading the same Excel file in the Drive UI and see if that works. It could be that Google Sheets is having problems converting that file.

Comment: Succesfuly uploaded file using google-api. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this code worked for me (using PyDrive):

```
f = drive.CreateFile({'title':'test.csv', 'mimeType':'text/csv'})
f.SetContentString('a,b\n1,2')
f.Upload(param={'convert': True})
```